# Exception in application start method with alert showAndWait

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, alert, show

I am learning JavaFX on my own. I searched in forums, but I have been unable to find a similar problem.

I am trying to get the type of button to close a confirmation alert:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Group g = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(g, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        Alert a = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        a.initOwner(primaryStage);
        a.setTitle("alert");
        a.setHeaderText("entête");
        a.setContentText("hi");
        a.show();

        a.showAndWait().ifPresent(response -> {
            if (response == ButtonType.OK) {
                System.out.println("rrrr");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

But I have this exception, and I don't know why:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stage already visible
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:451)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.HeavyweightDialog.showAndWait(HeavyweightDialog.java:162)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Dialog.showAndWait(Dialog.java:346)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:29)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have setup my IDE by following the "JavaFX and IntelliJ" section of this tutorial: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: First you call `show()`, and then `showAndWait()`. That looks at least a little redundant and suspicious. It could explain why the error complains about a state already being set to a certain state. Does it work without the first call to `show()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by the fact that you try to call `showAndWait()` on a stage that is already visible. From the [javadocs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html?is-external=true#showAndWait())

> Throws:
> `IllegalStateException` - if this stage is already showing.

If you delete the initial call `a.show();` this should fix your problem.